# Using Collectors.mapping(custom) to count frequence of letters in String

Tags: java, java-8

If I use the below snippet, I get a `Map<Character, Long>`, but I want a `Map<Character, Integer>`. How can I have my own custom mapper that I invoke via `Collectors.mapping`?

```
String str = "abcdefabcdghh";
char []vv = str.toCharArray();
var vvv = str.chars().mapToObj(i->(char)i)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))
```

Comment: Use `summingInt(i -> 1)`

Comment: You can also replace `mapToInt()` with `boxed()`.

Comment: Not sure what `mapping()` has to do with anything.

Comment: @shmosel `boxed()` will return a `Stream<Integer>`, not a `Stream<Character>`.

Answer (score 3):

The counting is just a reduce function with `Long::sum` accumulator

```java
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Long> counting() {
    return reducing(0L, e -> 1L, Long::sum);
}
```

You can safely adapt this code replacing `Long` by `Integer`

```java
String str = "abcdefabcdghh";
char []vv = str.toCharArray();
var vvv = str.chars()
             .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                            Collectors.reducing(0,
                                                                e -> 1,
                                                                Integer::sum)));
```